# A couple ASP questions

Tags: asp-classic

Can anyone tell me what each of these are doing?

**<%call buildBanner()%>**
What I think this one is doing is calling a Method But I'm not that familiar with ASP.

**Dim nInstallID : nInstallID = getParam("InstallID")**
This I'm not quite sure, But from What I gathered it's a string. But I'm not sure what the ":" does or is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "call buildBanner()" is calling a function from somewhere else in your code.  The function could be on the same page or it could be in an "include" file.

The ":" is just a way to separate commands on the same line.  Normally you would put the two parts on two separate lines, but this is a shortcut way to use one line.  Some people like to declare and initialize the variable on the same line - something you can't do in a single statement in Classic ASP.

Comment: Not a fan of the `:` method.

Comment: Thank you Phillip that helped me out

Comment: Been developing ASP for over a decade, first I've seen the colon separator. Thanks for the new tidbit Phillip.